# Find Sign when Sign Changes in Pandas Column while Ignoring Zeros using Vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to find a vectorized way of determining the first instance where my column of data has a sign change. I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764107/detect-sign-changes-in-pandas-dataframe) and it gets close to what I want, except it evaluates my first zeros as true. I'm open to different solutions including changing how the data is set up in the first place. I'll detail what I'm doing below.

I have two columns, let's call them positive and negative, that look at a third column. The third column has values ranging between [-5, 5]. When this column is [3, 5], my positive column gets a +1 on that same row; all other rows are 0 in that column. Likewise, when the third column is between [-5, -3], my negative column gets a -1 in that row; all other rows are 0.

I combine these columns into one column. You can conceptualize this as 'turn machine on, keep it on/off, turn it off, keep it on/off, turn machine on ... etc.' The problem I've having is that my combined column looks something like below:

```
pos = [1,1,1,0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,1, 0,1]
neg = [0,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0]
com = [1,1,1,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1]
# Below is what I want to have as the final column.
cor = [1,0,0,0,-1, 0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1]
```

The problem with what I've linked is that it gets close, but it evaluates the first 0 as a sign change as well. 0's should be ignored and I tried a few things, but seem to be creating new errors. For the sake of completeness, this is what the code linked outputs:

```
lnk = [True,False,False,True,True,False,True,False,False,False,True,True,True]
```

As you can see, it's doing the 1 and -1 not flipping fine, but the zero's it's flipping. Not sure if I should change how the combined column is made or if I should change the logic for the creation of the component columns, both. The big thing is I need to vectorize this code for performance concerns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your dataframe is named `df` with columns `pos` and `neg` then you can try something like the following :

```py
df.loc[:, "switch_pos"] = (np.diff(df.pos, prepend=0) > 0)*1

df.loc[:, "switch_neg"] = (np.diff(df.neg, prepend=0) > 0)*(-1)
```

You can then combine your two switchs columns.

### Explanations

`no.diff` gives you the difference row by row but setting (for pos columns) 1 for 0 to 1 and - 1 for 1 to 0. Considering your desired output, you want to keep only your 0 to 1, that's why you need to keep only the more than zero output

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply. I tried it out and I think it's still doing the behavior I described above. When the values are continuously positive, it only puts True on the first positive value. It doesn't put true on any zero values, which is an improvement, but if there's another positive value shortly afterwards, then it flips it positive. So, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 , 1 returns T,F,F,F,F,T when it shouldn't. It should return T on the next negative number.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I took the indexes of the pos and the indexes of the negs, unioned them, then did what I linked to get the sign changes, then took that and using the same indexes, reassigned to my array to get a truth value, then took the truth value to override the false to 0s and keep the truths to their original value.